# dynamic combo box with ajax in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

i want make dinamic combo box in laravel , i make like this , its my ajax cript in my view

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#vendor').change(function(){
      var vendor = $('vendor').val();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url : '{{url('/getInvoiceNo')}}',

        data:{
          "_token":"{{csrf_token()}}",
          'vendorId' : vendor
        }, 
        success: function(data){
          $('#invoice').html($return);
        }

      });
    });

  });
```

and i have this function in my controller

```html
 public function getInvoiceNo(Request $request)
    {
        $data = invoice::all()->where('VendorId', '=', $request->vendorId);

       $return = '<option value=""></option>';
        foreach($data as $row) 
        $return .= "<option value='$row->id'>$row->InvoiceNo</option>";
         echo ($return);

    }
```

but this sintaks still an error , when i run $return is no found and combo box invoice is not change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have this in your route:

```
Route::get('/get-invoice-no', 'Controller@getInvoiceNo')
```

the dropdown function:

```
$('#vendor').change(function(){
      var vendor = $('vendor').val();
      $.get('get-invoice-no',
      {
        id:$(this).val()
      },function(data,status){
        $('#invoice').empty();
        $('#invoice').append('<option value=''>$row->Select Invoice</option>');
        $.each(data,function(index,value){
            $('#invoice').append('<option class="select" value="'+value['id']+'">'+value['InvoiceNo']+'</option>')
        });
      });
    }
```

What's your route should be:

```
 public function getInvoiceNo(Request $request)
 {
   $data = invoice::where('VendorId','=', $request->vendorId)->get();
   return $data;       
 }
```

But you have to make sure that you have invoice model also. :)